# TypeError: 'Chat' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу телеграмм бота, при команде */start* он выводит в консоль данные о группе к которой подключен методом **bot.get_chat(id)**. 
Выводит он
   `{'type': 'group', 'last_name': None, 'first_name': None, 'username': None, 'id': 3434919, 'title': 'Группа1', 'all_members_are_administrators': False, 'photo': None, 'description': None, 'invite_link': None, 'pinned_message': None, 'sticker_set_name': None, 'can_set_sticker_set': None}`

---

Я делаю : 

`data = bot.get_chat(id)
print(data['title'])`

и вылезает ошибка **TypeError: 'Chat' object is not subscriptable**. Почему так? Как мне вытащить значение *'title'* ?
Использую библиотеку *pytelegrambotapi*

Comment: Попробуйте `print(str(data.title))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `Chat` не имеет функционала для обращения к элементам через квадратные скобки, в чём легко можно убедиться по исходному коду:

https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/2d6c2a345f078d66ec05f2ced501012703bb0bdb/telebot/types.py

Вместо этого к аттрибуту `title` следует обращаться напрямую. То есть в вашем случае нужно писать `data.title` вместо `data['title']`